# Write a mode method in Java to find the least frequently occurring element in an array

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I have arraylist of strings that have data of kind like this 
{"this","is",is","repeating"}

i need a java code that will give me the element(s)  which is least repeating

the output should be
this = 1
repeating = 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, it's a bit long but maybe there's some utils package that does the same (haven't found one so far):

```
    String[] words = {"this", "is", "is", "repeating"};

    TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> frequencyMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    for (String word : words) {
        Integer frequency = 0;
        for (String word2 : words) {
            if (word.equals(word2)) {
                frequency++;
            }
        }

        if (frequencyMap.containsKey(frequency)) {
            List<String> wordsWithFrequency = frequencyMap.get(frequency);
            wordsWithFrequency.add(word);
        } else {
            List<String> wordsWithFrequency = new ArrayList<String>();
            wordsWithFrequency.add(word);
            frequencyMap.put(frequency, wordsWithFrequency);
        }
    }

    if (frequencyMap.size() > 0) {
        List<String> leastFrequentWords = frequencyMap.get(frequencyMap.firstKey());
        for (String string : leastFrequentWords) {
            System.out.println(string + " = " + frequencyMap.firstKey());
        }
    }
```

This prints out:

```
this = 1
repeating = 1
```